# react-router error of routerWillLeave in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, react-router

I will get an error '缺少对象'(maybe 'Missing object' in English) in IE8 when I will go to another route from the route which have a routerWillLeave function but it's parent route doesn't have.
For example, I have three route:

```
<Route path="employees" component={Employees}>
    <Route path=":id/edit" component={EmployeesEdit} />
</Route>
<Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```

Component Employees doesn't have routerWillLeave function, but EmployeesEdit has. When I go to /dashboard from /employees/:id/edit I will get the error. But, when I go to /employees from /employees/:id/edit I won't.
I don't know why, but after I adding a routerWillLeave to component Employees I won't get the error anymore.

The error will occur in IE8, but not in Chrome.